# Split Visual Studio between SSD and HDD

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a fairly small SSD(120gb) and I was wondering if I can put just the main program on the SSD for the faster load times, but then put some parts such as mobile dev or python dev on the HDD to save space on my SSD

Comment: starting with VS2017 15.7, [you can install a lot of data to other drives](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/04/09/visual-studio-2017-version-15-7-preview-3/)

Answer (score 0):

When installing Visual Studio you are able to enter a custom installation directory. This directory will contain the editor, build tools, debugger, SDK for native applications etc. This will look like this:

```
04/10/2018  09:25    <DIR>          .
04/10/2018  09:25    <DIR>          ..
27/09/2018  13:20    <DIR>          Common7
27/09/2018  13:22    <DIR>          DesignTools
27/09/2018  13:26    <DIR>          DIA SDK
04/10/2018  09:25    <DIR>          ImportProjects
27/09/2018  13:23    <DIR>          JavaScript
27/09/2018  13:23    <DIR>          JS
04/10/2018  09:25    <DIR>          Licenses
27/09/2018  13:23    <DIR>          MSBuild
27/09/2018  13:26    <DIR>          SDK
27/09/2018  13:22    <DIR>          Team Tools
27/09/2018  13:23    <DIR>          TS
27/09/2018  13:23    <DIR>          VB
27/09/2018  13:26    <DIR>          VC
04/10/2018  09:25    <DIR>          VC#
27/09/2018  13:24    <DIR>          Web
04/10/2018  09:25    <DIR>          Xml
```

In addition to that, VS installer will occupy the one or other GB in `%PROGRAMFILES%` (e.g. for Windows SDKs) depending on what features you are actually installing. There is no way documented how to coustomize this installation path.

So finally there is no way to achieve, what you aim for. I would have appreaciated more customization too.